# MVC plug ins with Pre compiled views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mef, precompiled-views

I recently implemented a plug in framework using MEF to include exteranl MVC projects and all is working fine. However, trying to precompile the site does not allow the plug in views to be precomipled which makes sense given that they are not included in the project. Is there any way to accomplish this even if I drop in the plug in before publishing the main project out. Any related info is helpful.